# svg groups and fill inheritance

Tags: svg

My goal is to have the first group of 3 squares be blue and the next group of 3 squares be red. To minimize code, I want to take advantage of grouping in SVG.  All the rectangles remain blue. I have tried inline styling on the second group element and on the use element, but that doesn't solve the problem.  Thank you for your assistance.. Here's the code:

```
<svg width="1000" height="800" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<style>
.blue {fill:blue;}
.red {fill:red;}
</style>

<g id="g1" class="blue">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    <rect x="0" y="105" width="100" height="100" />
    <rect x="0" y="210" width="100" height="100" />
</g>

<g class="red">
<use xlink:href="#g1" transform="translate(0,315)"  />
</g>
```

Here are changes from above that now have it working:

```
<g class="blue">
<g id="g1">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    <rect x="0" y="105" width="100" height="100" />
    <rect x="0" y="210" width="100" height="100" />
</g>
</g>

<g class="red" transform="translate(0,315)">
<use xlink:href="#g1" />
<!-- <g id="g1">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    <rect x="0" y="105" width="100" height="100" />
    <rect x="0" y="210" width="100" height="100" />
</g> -->
</g>
```

... I commented out some of the old svg as well.

Here's the solution in a clearer form  (some of the commented code above, actually came from further experimenting).

```
<svg width="1000" height="800" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<style>
.blue {fill:blue;}
.red {fill:red;}
</style>


<g class="blue">
<g id="g1">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    <rect x="0" y="105" width="100" height="100" />
    <rect x="0" y="210" width="100" height="100" />
</g>
</g>

<g class="red" transform="translate(0,315)">
<use xlink:href="#g1" />
</g>
```

Looks like styling needs to be done at a level above a group in my case and that the  as Robert pointed out will retrieve the previous group as written.

Comment: If you need different styles don't use `<use>` The use tag is for multiple views of the same thing.

Comment: Thank you - I have a better understanding now.  Also, it looks like the problem is solved - I don't know if I should edit my original post now - but I wrapped the blue group in a new group with the class blue, and that seems to have done the trick.